# Interaction with ng-change and select - changing data source triggers change

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Please examine this plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/ke4Cjg3gnf2pWUKW1f2b?p=preview.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('controller', ['$scope', '$timeout', function($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.items = [
      {name:'candy'},
      {name:'chocolate'}
    ];
    $scope.choice = null;

    $scope.test = function() { 
      console.log( 'fired' );
    }
    
    $timeout( function(){
      $scope.choice = $scope.items[0];
    }, 2000);
    
    $timeout( function(){
      $scope.items = [
        {name:'hershey'},
        {name:'mint'}
      ];
    }, 5000);
}]);
```

And

```html
    <select 
      ng-model="choice" 
      ng-options="item as item.name for item in items"
      ng-change="test()">
    </select>
```

I have a select box that uses ng-options and an ng-change event. Ng-change documentation states as follows:

> The ngChange expression is only evaluated when a change in the input value causes a new value to be committed to the model.
>
> It will not be evaluated:
>
> - if the value returned from the $parsers transformation pipeline has
>     not changed
> - if the input has continued to be invalid since the model will stay null
> - if the model is changed programmatically and not by a change to the input value

Obviously if I programmatically set the model equal to something, nothing happens, but I'm finding that when I change the source of ng-options dynamically, ng-change is firing **unless** ng-model equals a value of null at the time that the results are changed.

Is this a bug or intended? If intended, how can I change the source of ng-options without causing ng-change to fire without setting ng-model to null first? If not, I'll go and report this strange behavior.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what's happening:

1. You select a value from the dropdown (e.g. candy).
2. After the timeout. a new array is created within $scope.items.  At this point, angularjs will repopulate the HTML dropdown box (select) with a new set of items.  This will cause the element within the DOM to change its value from a previously selected one (e.g. candy) to null.
3. This change causes the ng-change expression to be evaluated.

This is valid because a) there is a change (from candy to null) and b) the change was not done through a programmatic change to the model (but to the underlying DOM element.

The way to solve if varies depending on what you want to do.  In the example you provided, the underlying value will always change because the new options replace all the old ones.  But consider the following example where I opt to remove chocolate and add two new values (keeping the candy option):

```
$timeout( function(){
  delete $scope.items[1]; // removes item choclate from the list.

  // Add new items
  $scope.items[1] = {name : 'hershey' };
  $scope.items[2] = {name : 'mint' };

}, 5000);
```

In this case if the user selects "candy" ng-change does not fire since the selected option remains the same.  On the other hand if the user selects "chocolate", the change will fire (since the value goes from "chocolate" to null).  So here are some options you may want to consider:

1. Only add items to the drop down.
2. Set the value to null if the selected option needs to be removed (this does not fire because you are setting the model programmatically).
3. Replace the whole array such that ng-change fires but perform checks within the function called by ng-change so as to handle cases where the model did not fire.

Comment: Ah, thank you, you're right, I wasn't looking at it that way. Still, it does seem like something that would have made more sense to not function that way.

Comment: Thank you for the choices. I ran into the same problem and was trying to figure out what the best way to fix it was.